# full width carousel in bootstrap 4 (alpha 6)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-12">
        <div class="">
        <div class="row">
        <section class="col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel slide" id="featured" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="_images/Slider_1.jpg" alt="slider1">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="_images/Slider_2.jpg" alt="slider2">

    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">


        <h3>Jadon Events</h3>
        <p>We organize your events like you cannot even imagine</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="_images/Slider_3.jpg" alt="slider3">
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </span></a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </span></a>
</div>
            </section>
            </div>
    </div>
```

I have figured out how to make slider in bootstrap, but now I am stuck with full width slider.
how can I make my carousel full width? I removed container classes but it makes some scroll at bottom which is not good for responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and change images with yours.

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="featured" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/2100x300" alt="slider1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/2100x300" alt="slider2">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h3>Jadon Events</h3>
                    <p>We organize your events like you cannot even imagine</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/2100x300" alt="slider3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
```